# Binary overloaded operator=

Tags: c++, c++11

So I'm trying to write and read from a file, using `std::ostream_iterator` and `std::iostream_iterator`. The process of writng works well without any mistakes. But as for reading I'm lost. The error, I have is:

> 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility(2316): error C2678: binary '=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const WRstruct' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

and it says that:

> c:\users\xxxxxxx\desktop\ttttt\ttttt\wrstruct.h(21): note: could be 'WRstruct &WRstruct::operator =(const WRstruct &)'
>   1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility(2316): note: while trying to match the argument list '(const WRstruct, WRstruct)'

What is the correct way of overloading `operator=`?

**class:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <istream>

class WRstruct
{
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string number;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const WRstruct&);
    friend std::istream& operator >> ( std::istream& is, WRstruct&);

public:
    WRstruct(){};
    void write();
    void read();
    ~WRstruct(){};
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const WRstruct& p)
{
    os << "User Name: " << p.name << std::endl
        << "Name: " << p.number << std::endl
        << std::endl;
    return os;
}

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, WRstruct& p)
{

    is >> p.name>>p.number;
    return is;
}
```

Methods:

```
void WRstruct::write()
{
    std::vector<WRstruct> vecP;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<WRstruct>(std::cin),
    std::istream_iterator<WRstruct>(), std::back_inserter(vecP));
    std::ofstream temp("temp.txt", std::ios::out);
    std::ostream_iterator<WRstruct>temp_itr(temp, "\n");
    std::copy(vecP.begin(), vecP.end(), temp_itr);

}

void WRstruct::read()
{
    std::vector<WRstruct> vec;

    std::ifstream readFile("temp.txt");
    std::istream_iterator<WRstruct> istr(readFile);
    copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), istr);

    std::istream_iterator<WRstruct> end_istr;
    copy(istr, end_istr, back_inserter(vec));

    std::ostream_iterator<WRstruct> osIter(std::cout," ");
    copy(vec.begin(),vec.end(),osIter);

}
```

and main():

```
#include <iostream>
#include "WRstruct.h"

int main()
{
    WRstruct r;
    r.write();
    //r.read();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but your structures input operator will not be able to read what your output operator writes. Also, they should be marked as either `static` or `inline` or else you will have problems when you try to use the class from multiple source files ([*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))). You should also have some [header include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Comment: Could you please comment on line `copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), istr);`? In this line you're trying to copy data from a `vector` (which is empty) to `istream` (which is read-only). It looks very-very strange. Perhaps the mistake is in this line.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 Oh the vector isn't empty, it should have been populated above from `std::cin`.

Comment: @X21 -- Another side note -- don't write empty destructors (`~WRstruct()`).  The compiler may not optimize the code as well if it encounters that you've written a destructor (instead of relying on the compiler's default destructor).  Write a user-defined destructor when you actually need one.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude     Could you please show , how I should to do this ? Because I had never met using `static` or `inline` marked

Comment: `friend std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& is, WRstruct&);` mb? instead `friend std::istream& operator>>   ( std::istream& is, WRstruct&);`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Looks like we're talking about different things. I mean line 4 of `WRstruct::read`. The vector `vec` used in it is empty.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 Ah, I looked at a very similar line in the `write` function (which have now been edited). You found the problem though and should write it as an answer.

Comment: U use spaces between the 'operator' and the '>>' try to remove its.

Comment: Use `'\n'`, not `std::endl`.  The latter flushes the output buffer, which can be expensive.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0   I have edited this , because `write` had the same part of code of `read` function (sorry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, the meaning of your function `WRstruct::read` is "reading all the data from 'temp.txt' and writing it to console". *BTW, it's strange that function `read` prints something, so consider naming your function accordingly.*

To read something from file using `istream_iterator`, you should create a pair of iterators (one pointing to the beginning of the file, and another empty) and use `std::copy`. So, the reading part of your function should look like

```
std::vector<WRstruct> vec;

std::ifstream readFile("temp.txt");
std::istream_iterator<WRstruct> istr(readFile);
std::istream_iterator<WRstruct> end_istr;
copy(istr, end_istr, back_inserter(vec));
```

So, you can just comment or delete one line from `WRstruct::read` to get rid of compilation error.

Comment: Please comment if meaning of `WRstruct::read` function should be different.

Comment: can I edit the code in order to show that after all changes I have another erros? One of them is : `error LNK2005: "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class WRstruct const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABVWRstruct@@@Z) already defined in Source.obj
1>C:\Users\Nikita Gusev\Desktop\ttttt\Debug\ttttt.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found` . Or sjould I ask another question?

Comment: @X21, I think it's better to create another question. Using the code from this question, I cannot reproduce this second error message